# Difference in C main function declarations

Tags: c, constants

I'm a beginner with the langage C and i'd like to know what's the difference between this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
```

and this:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
```

I think it's the same thing but i'm not sure. Could someone explain me the difference.

Thank you

Comment: read about const... http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/const-qualifier-in-c/

Comment: To a degree its the same thing, but `const` tells the compiler you are not supposed to be able to change the values in `argv`. If you try, the code will throw an error and not compile. `const` is relevant to the optimizer, and should be used when you want to give the compiler optimization hints. Since you are just beginning with C, I wouldn't worry about that just yet.

Answer (score 1):

`int main(int argc, char * argv[])` is correct and must be accepted by the compiler.

`int main(int argc, const char * argv[])` may be rejected by the compiler. If the compiler accepts it then the behaviour is *implementation-defined*.  This means that the compiler must document which non-standard signatures of `main` it accepts, and document the behaviour of each one.

So, consult your compiler's documentation to see what it says about parameters of `main`.  A reasonable expectation would be that the compiler makes this form behave the same as if you had `int main(int argc, char *__argv[]) {  const char **argv = (const char **)__argv;` .

Answer (score 0):

I guess firstly you have to know `const char* c;` and `char *const c;`

1. In `const char* c`, const means you can't change the content `c` points to.
2. In `char *const c`, const means you can't change the position `c` points to.

As you know, the value stored in `char* c` is an address in memory, so the first `const` indicates that the value that `c` points to isn't supposed to be changed.And the second one indicates that the value of `c` shouldn't be changed.

Thus, in `const char * argv[]`, `argv` is an array of `const char*` variables.This means the content that every element in `argv` points to is constant.Actually, each element points to a string, and `argv` is an array of strings storing "arguments" that CL passes to you.It's true that you can only read the arguments but modifying them.
Of course, compiler won't block you if `const` is missed here.If so, you can change the content of strings in your code and I guess nothing will happen, since these arguments are for you to read.  :)